# Rails engine tutorial warning (Configuring an Engine)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On RailsGuides [Section 4.4 Configuring an engine](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#configuring-an-engine), the following cautionary statement is given:

> It's very important here to use the String version of the class,
> rather than the class itself. If you were to use the class, Rails
> would attempt to load that class and then reference the related table.
> This could lead to problems if the table didn't already exist.
> Therefore, a String should be used and then converted to a class using
> constantize in the engine later on.

i.e. in the initializer, the correct way would be to state `Blorgh.author_class = "User"` and `Blorgh.author_class = User` is wrong.

I don't understand what the guide means by the table not existing (I assume it's the user table). If the user table doesn't exist at the point of initializing the application, it also wouldn't exist after running all initializations.

Additionally, since we are just supplying the ActiveRecord model class to the engine, why would there be a need to reference tables/do database queries?

Comment: Rails examines the table structure when an ActiveRecord class is instantiated, so the table has to exist at that point. Engines still require running migrations, so there is potentially a point post-install where there is a class in your initializer for which there is no table. `db:migrate` loads Rails, Rails tries to load the class, and errors because there is no table.

Comment: @rmlockerd thats actually a pretty good answer.

Comment: @rmlockerd Thanks for your answer. Just to paraphrase the last sentence for my personal learning, running any rails command like db:migrate calls the initialisers first, so there shouldn't any reference to an ActiveRecord class there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails examines the table structure when an ActiveRecord class is instantiated, so the table has to exist at that point. Engines that add models require database migrations to run, so if you reference an ActiveRecord model in an initializer, there is a point post-install where there the reference class has no table.

The `db:migrate` task loads Rails (thus running the initializers), so you end up with a chicken-and-egg problem where you can't add the new table because Rails tries to load the class and there is no table. Thus it is better to set the class as a String and then use `constantize` at runtime to instantiate the class.